# Decomposition of a polynomial of the form $X^{p^n}-X$ in finite fields.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am studying fields theory and Galois theory as an undergraduate, and as such we are studying finite fields and their properties.

In this case, I was wondering about a common procedure for which I did not have a detailed explanation in my notes.

Let's take the following example:

It is requested to decompose $X^{16}-X$ into $\mathbb{F}_4$ and $\mathbb{F}_8$, where $\mathbb{F}_n$ refers to the Galois field of $n$ elements.

I understand that the difficulty lies in the fact that determining the irreducibility of polynomials in finite fields is not a trivial problem.

The problem can be generalized, for example asking to decompose $X^{(p^n)}-X$ into $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ where $p\in\mathbb{N}$ is a prime and $m\leq n$.

I understand that the procedure to be carried out will have to do with decomposition fields and Moore's theorem, but I would like to know if someone can provide a detailed explanation, even if it is for a particular case, or refer me to a source where I can find it.

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Comment: Comment 1: your generalisation doesn't cover the two specific cases as $8=2^3$, $16=2^4$ and $3$ does not divide $4$. But good,  I suspect you know the basic fact that $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ iff $m\mid n$ which is useful here.

Comment: Comment 2. Do you know that the $16$ roots of $X^{16}-X$ form the field of $16$ elements, $\mathbb{F}_{16}$?

Comment: Hint: given comments 1, 2 I would start by factorising $X^{16}-X$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. I would expect to get two linear factors to provide the two elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$; one quadratic factor to provide also the other two elements of $\mathbb{F}_4$, and then three quartics to provide the other twelve elements of $\mathbb{F}_{16}$.

Comment: Hint 2: There are only $16$ monic quartics over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and it takes less than ten minutes to exclude the ones with a root, and another  moment to exclude the one which is the square of the only irreducible quadratic. So you'll find the three irreducible quartics easily.

Comment: Hint 3: You now need to factorise the polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{F}_2(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is a root of $X^2+X+1$. Each of the quartics must factorise into two quadratics. This is going to be a little tedious ... which is why I haven't written an answer.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks por your comments. True, my generalization was wrong. I edited the post according to your comment 1.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, I know that the 16 roots of $X^{16}-X$ form the field $\mathbb{F}_{16}$. More precisely, I know that $X^q=X$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_q$ and that all subgroups of the multiplicative group of a finite field must be cyclic.

Comment: @ancientmathematician For Hint 1: Yes. I am following you. So, you have $X^{16}-X=X(X+1)(X^2+X+1)(X^4+X+1)(X^4+X^3+1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$ and there aren't any more irreducible quartics in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$  other than the ones in the former decomposition for your given argument (either they have roots on $\mathbb{F}_2$ or they are exactly the polynomial $(X^2+X+1)^2=X^4+X^2+1$). Did I catch it?

Comment: @ancientmathematician And it only rests to finish Hint 3.

Comment: Yes, getting there. I think that it's easy to find out and easier to check that $X^4+X+1=(X^2+X+\omega)((X^2+X+\omega^2)$, which will give the reverse quartic $X^4+X^3+1$ as well. The other I leave to you. BTWI think it's clear that over $\mathbb{F}_8$ the $\mathbb{F}_2$ factorisation stands. Perhaps you could self-answer the question :-)